# python django analyze a file for a list of keywords

Tags: python, django

I have a list of keywords that I need to ensure are not present in a string.
This string could be either plain text or plain text with svn or git repository syntax in it such as a patch. 
How exactly would you implement this search in the python/django environment; regex, loop, grep? I'd ideally also like to get the line where it happens to I can display it to user.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of how your text file is structured?

Comment: It's basically c++ code with svn tags so headers and footers have things such as +++++++++++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
import re

BAD_WORDS = ["spam", "ham"]
BAD_WORDS_RE = re.compile(r"\b(%s)\b" % "|".join(BAD_WORDS))

for i, line in enumerate(open("file.txt").readlines()):
    words = set(BAD_WORDS_RE.findall(line))
    if words:
        print "Found the following words on line %i: %s" % (i + 1, ", ".join(words))
        print line
```

Answer (score 1):

```python
txt = open('the_file.txt', 'r').read()
for keyword in ['foo', 'bar']:
    if keyword in txt:
        # Do something for when the keyword is found
        print 'Matched keyword %s' % keyword
```